# Ive got a pipe that consists of 5 pieces, each including 5 properties

Tags: database, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

Inlet -> front -> middle -> rear -> outlet

Those five properties have a value anything between 4 - 40. Now i want to calculate a specific match for each of those values that is either a full 10 or a 5 when a single property is summed from each pipe piece. There might be hundreds of different pipe pieces all with different properties.

So if i have all 5 pieces and when summed, their properties go like 54,51,23,71,37. That is not good and not what im looking.

Instead 55,50,25,70,40. That would be perfect.

My trouble is there are so many of the pieces that it would be insane to do the miss'matching manually, and new ones come up frequently.

I have manually inserted about 100 of these already into SQLite, but should be easy to convert into any excel or other database formats, so answer can be related to anything like mysql or googlesheets.

I need the calculation that takes every piece in account and results either in "no match" or tells me the id of each piece that is required for a match and if multiple matches are available, it separates them.

Edit: Even just the math needed to do this kind of calculation would be a lot of help here, not much of a math guy myself. I guess there should be a reference piece i need to use and then that gets checked against every possible scenario.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a pipe that's too short if you use 50 for a 51 pipe?

Comment: can you attach a minimal reproduceable example

Answer (score 1):

If the value you want to verify is in A1, use: `=ROUND(A1/5,0)*5`

If the pipes may not be shorter than the given values, use `=CEILING(A1,5)`